# Pattern for user signup/login in HTML5 app

Tags: javascript, html, asynchronous, parse-platform

What is a good pattern for establishing a user session (including signup or login) in a Javascript/HTML5 app?

Specifically, I'm wondering how to delay displaying the main interface and initialising features until the async login is completed.

My app uses requirejs for modules, Parse for the backend (which is a NoSQL interface based on Backbone and MongoDB iirc). The main interface is currently simply hidden until app init completes and then made visible via CSS.

I am looking for a proper pattern to do this; the specifics of which libraries I'm using is only given for a little context. I suppose this is a basic Javascript question, but I can find it confusing to know how to wait for async calls. While I understand Promises, I am not sure for instance how to apply them to delaying initialising of separate modules...

Comment: parse.com is shutting down. Please don't waste your time learning parse specific syntax and practices.

Comment: That's not my question

Comment: check github for 'parseUI...' projects a number of lang implementations are there.. check webcomponent lists for 'signup/login'   https://customelements.io/